# data List - checking if a list is empty

Tags: list, haskell, syntactic-sugar

I have the following. It just simply checks if a `List` is empty. However if I try to run it with `main`, I get an error. How do I need to change the `main` function to run it properly?

```
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)

vnull :: List a -> Bool
vnull Nil = True 
vnull _ = False 

main = do print (vnull [1,2])
```

The error is the following:

```
Couldn't match expected type `List a0' with actual type `[Integer]'
   In the first argument of `vnull', namely `[1, 2]'
   In the first argument of `print', namely `(vnull [1, 2])'
   In a stmt of a 'do' block: print (vnull [1, 2])
```

Comment: `print` will need you to add `deriving Show` at the end of the data declaration for `List`

Comment: Unrelated tip: you don't need `do` if you have just one `IO` action (in your case, the `print`ing).

Comment: btw. `fromList = foldr Cons Nil` is a really handy function when doing this like that.

Answer (score 1):

Changing to:

```
main = print $ vnull $ Cons 1 $ Cons 2 Nil
```

produces:

```
False
```

Answer (score 1):

it is working like it is implemented:

```
vnull Nil
True

vnull (Cons 1 Nil)
False

vnull (Cons 2 (Cons 1 Nil)
False

...
```

you can try following commands in `ghci`, to get all information about `[]` datatype:

```
Prelude> :t []
[] :: [t]
Prelude> :i []
data [] a = [] | a : [a]    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Types’
instance Eq a => Eq [a] -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
instance Monad [] -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
instance Functor [] -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
instance Ord a => Ord [a] -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
instance Read a => Read [a] -- Defined in ‘GHC.Read’
instance Show a => Show [a] -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
instance Applicative [] -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
instance Foldable [] -- Defined in ‘Data.Foldable’
instance Traversable [] -- Defined in ‘Data.Traversable’
instance Monoid [a] -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
```

for your function to be applicable to `[]` parameter you need something like:

```
vnull ::  [a] -> Bool
vnull [] = True
vnull _ = False
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to use your `List` type with the usual list syntax, you'll have to use GHC extensions.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedLists, TypeFamilies #-} -- at the very top of the file

import qualified GHC.Exts as E
import Data.Foldable

data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a) deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

instance Foldable List where
  foldr _ n Nil = n
  foldr c n (Cons x xs) = x `c` foldr c n xs

instance E.IsList List where
  type Item (List a) = a

  fromList = foldr Cons Nil
  toList = toList
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List a
```

and

```
[]
```

Are two different constructors and not the same data type, The function would work for a **List a** type, so instead of "**[]**" try this:

```
 vnull :: List a -> Bool
 vnull Nil = True
 vnull (Cons a expand) = False
```

Then in main

```
main = do print (vnull $ Cons 1 (Cons 2 Nil)) --This is just an example you can throw in a -List a- type of any length.
```

And this should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are missing:

```
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a) deriving Show

fromList = foldr Cons Nil

vnull :: List a -> Bool
vnull Nil = True 
vnull _ = False 

main = do print (vnull $ fromList [1,2])
```

The deriving Show is not necessary now, but will be, when you actually want to print a List and not a Bool. The fromList function does nothing, but to convert the Haskell Listimplementation (here [1,2]) into your own, so you can call vnull on it. You could have also called

`main = do print $ vnull (Cons 1 (Cons 2 (Nil)))`

Answer (score -1):

You can:

`instance Foldeable List where
  foldMap f Nil = mempty
  foldMap f (Cons x ls) = mappend (f x) (foldMap ls)`

Then use `(fold [1,2])::List Int`

Comment: The class is called `Foldable`. More importantly, its `fold` method doesn't do what you're asking of it.